# The proxy address "smtp:email@domain..com" is already used by the proxy address or LegacyExchangeDN

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2016

when attempting to remove email addresses of MailContacts in Exchange Server 2016 using the following cmd:

```
Set-MailContact -Identity "bob" -EmailAddresses @{ remove="SMTP:bob@domain.com" } -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false
```

The command works in most cases, however for some email addresses it fails:

```
“The proxy address "SMTP:bob@domain.com" is already being used by the proxy addresses or 
LegacyExchangeDN of "domain.com/Exchange/Bob2". Please choose another 
proxy address. “
```

Running command:

```
Get-MailContact -Filter "EmailAddresses -eq 'bob@domain.com'"
```

Outputs the following:

```
Name                      Alias                                          RecipientType
----                      -----                                          -------------
bob@domain.com            bob?domain.com                                MailContact
Bob.Smith                 Bob.Smith                                     MailContact
```

What is the best way to remove this email address from the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the email address is used by other recipients (but why?). Anyway you need to resolv the conflicts manually.

The error shows you the identity of account with "problem" smtp address and you can find him in ADUC or in powershell.
Firstly check the email addresses are used by `bob` account with command:

```
Get-MailContact -Identity bob | fl DisplayName,EmailAddresses,Alias
```

You'll receive something like that:

```
DisplayName    : Bob Smith
EmailAddresses : {smtp:bob@domain.com, SMTP:bob3@domain.com}
Alias          : bob
```

Than check the Bob2's mailbox and email addressess assigned to him:

```
Get-Mailbox bob2 | fl DisplayName,EmailAddresses,Alias
```

Expected output (example):

```
DisplayName    : Bob Smith 2
EmailAddresses : {SMTP:bob@domain.com}
Alias          : rogov.v.l
```

If you find any duplicated email addresses you need to remove them

Comment: Yes that is the problem. There are duplicatez, but the removal commands don't work because it says there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the duplicate email address with this method:

```
 $user = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(name=bob)" -Properties proxyAddresses 
 Set-ADObject $user.DistinguishedName -Remove @{proxyAddresses="SMTP:bob@domain.com"}
```

Comment: Very good you solved the problem. As i've mentioned above you need to remove attribute via ADUC (Active Directory Users and Computers) or with powershell. You've chosen the powershell